# Yii2 : read session data of any user from database

Tags: php, session, yii2

I'm creating an application using the Yii2 framework. The application contains role & permission kind of logic so I moved the session to the database level. My basic configuration is as below.

```
   'session' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\DbSession',
        'sessionTable' => 'user_session',
        'writeCallback' => function($session){
            return [
                'user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id,
                'last_write' => (new \yii\db\Expression('NOW()'))
            ];
        }
    ]
```

In the `user_session` table, each user's session is saved. My question is how can I modify/update particular user's session. I have a user id and from that, I can retrieve its session data. But can't modify it (I don't know how can I).

I tried `readSession()` method, but the data is in serialized form (I guess).

`__flash|a:0:{}id|s:26:"ajmj0p5r5gjub1d7cajf42n7v1";expire|s:10:"1508852343";data|s:1932...`.

How can I modify these data so the user may have new permission data if updated by the Admin user?

Comment: Session handler will automatically save session data as long as it gets modified. Try to set e.g. some flash message (`Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Hello 123')`) and check in the database if it changed.

Comment: @lubosdz It will modify the session for current user only. I want to modify session of any user. For example, I'm saving permission details in session. Suppose admin changes access permission for a particular user then the permission details session should also be updated, if the user is logged in to the system.

Comment: Uff, that's tricky & very unusual thing - modifying anyone's session data!! Besides corrupting your online user's data (think of session locking - write lock) it does not make much sense to me. Normally admins only modify user's data in the database and when user comes online, those database permissions will load & store into unique user's session data. You should NEVER modify directly anyone's session data. But technically it would be possible if you `start your session with particular user's session ID`. FYI this is also called `session_hijacking` and is known as hacking technique.